# Анимация поворота уже трансформированного элемента средствами CSS и JS

Tags: javascript, css, css-animation, transform, css-transform

На простенькой html-страничке я кнопками вращаю изображение. Если изображение вращать только кнопками `"повернуть по часовой"` и `"повернуть против часовой"`, то изображение вращается нормально. Но если сначала нажать, например, `"отразить по вертикали"` и потом по кнопкам `"повернуть по часовой"` и `"повернуть против часовой"` изображение вращается правильно, но анимация вращения идёт немного искаженная. Это возможно исправить быстро без прописывания по-кадровой анимации на каждую трансформацию?

```js
function disableButtons() {
  document.body.classList.add('disabled');
  setTimeout(() => document.body.classList.remove('disabled'), 1000);
}

rotate90.onclick = () => {
  disableButtons();
  let current = getComputedStyle(img).transform;
  if (current == 'none') current = '';
  img.style.transform = current + ' rotate(90deg)';
}

rotate270.onclick = () => {
  disableButtons();
  let current = getComputedStyle(img).transform;
  if (current == 'none') current = '';
  img.style.transform = current + ' rotate(-90deg)';
}

flipX.onclick = () => {
  disableButtons();
  let current = getComputedStyle(img).transform;
  if (current == 'none') current = '';
  img.style.transform = current + ' scaleY(-1)';
}

flipY.onclick = () => {
  disableButtons();
  let current = getComputedStyle(img).transform;
  if (current == 'none') current = '';
  img.style.transform = current + ' scaleX(-1)';
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  float: left;
  clear: right;
  width: max-content;
}

div button {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  user-select: none;
  margin: .3rem;
  border: 2px solid #f0f;
  cursor: pointer;
}

body {
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 2 2" fill="gray" stroke="none"><rect x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1"/><rect x="1" y="1" width="1" height="1"/></svg>') 16px/16px repeat;
  perspective: 100vh;
}

img,
.disabled * {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.disabled button {
  color: #666;
  background: #ddd;
  border: 2px solid #444;
}

.disabled button:hover {
  color: #666;
  background: #ddd;
  border: 2px solid #444;
}

img {
  transition: all 1000ms linear;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
  will-change: transform;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="rotate90">повернуть<br>по часовой</button>
  <button id="rotate270">повернуть<br>против часовой</button>
  <button id="flipX">отразить<br>по вертикали</button>
  <button id="flipY">отразить<br>по горизонтали</button>
</div>
<img id='img' src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1602251573001-a27aafb64d64?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHx0b3BpYy1mZWVkfDE4OXxxUFlzRHp2Sk9ZY3x8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&h=200&q=60" />
```

Comment: Может вам стоит добавить perspective свойство к своему css. И подсказать движку что вы собрались вращать через will-change:transform; 

[1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/perspective

Comment: `perspective` вроде не очень нужен ,все трансформации двухмерные. Но я все равно поставил, раз уж так хотите. `will-change` тоже установил. Но это ничего не меняет.

Comment: @BlackStar1991, похоже, надо `@keyframes` прописывать на каждую анимацию из каждой ориентации. `4х8 = 32` анимации прописывать конечно жесть.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Просто надо определить стейт и изменять его. Тогда не будет анимаций, что рисуются на основе прошлых движений

```js
const state = {
  rotate: 0,
  scaleX: 1,
  scaleY: 1,
  translateX: 0,
  translateY: 0,
};

function transformImage({ rotate, scaleY, scaleX, translateX, translateY }) {
  disableButtons();
  state.rotate += rotate || 0;
  state.scaleX *= scaleX || 1;
  state.scaleY *= scaleY || 1;
  state.translateX += translateX || 0;
  state.translateY += translateY || 0;
  img.style.transform = `translateX(${state.translateX}px) translateY(${state.translateY}px) rotate(${state.rotate}deg) scaleY(${state.scaleY}) scaleX(${state.scaleX})`;
}

function disableButtons() {
  document.body.classList.add('disabled');
  setTimeout(() => document.body.classList.remove('disabled'), 1000);
}

rotate90.onclick = () => transformImage({ rotate: -90 });
rotate270.onclick = () => transformImage({ rotate: 90 });
flipX.onclick = () => transformImage({ scaleX: -1 });
flipY.onclick = () => transformImage({ scaleY: -1 });
zoomOut.onclick = () => transformImage({ scaleX: 0.5, scaleY: 0.5 });
zoomIn.onclick = () => transformImage({ scaleX: 2, scaleY: 2 });
moveTop.onclick = () => transformImage({ translateY: -100 });
moveBottom.onclick = () => transformImage({ translateY: 100 });
moveLeft.onclick = () => transformImage({ translateX: -100 });
moveRight.onclick = () => transformImage({ translateX: 100 });
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  float: left;
  clear: right;
  width: max-content;
}

div button {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  user-select: none;
  margin: .3rem;
  border: 2px solid #f0f;
  cursor: pointer;
}

body {
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 2 2" fill="gray" stroke="none"><rect x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1"/><rect x="1" y="1" width="1" height="1"/></svg>') 16px/16px repeat;
  perspective: 100vh;
}

img,
.disabled * {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.disabled button {
  color: #666;
  background: #ddd;
  border: 2px solid #444;
}

.disabled button:hover {
  color: #666;
  background: #ddd;
  border: 2px solid #444;
}

img {
  transition: all 1000ms linear;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
  will-change: transform;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="rotate90">повернуть<br>по часовой</button>
  <button id="rotate270">повернуть<br>против часовой</button>
  <button id="flipX">отразить<br>по вертикали</button>
  <button id="flipY">отразить<br>по горизонтали</button>
  <button id="zoomIn">Увеличить</button>
  <button id="zoomOut">Уменшить</button>
  <button id="moveTop">Top</button>
  <button id="moveBottom">Bottom</button>
  <button id="moveLeft">Left</button>
  <button id="moveRight">Right</button>
</div>
<img id='img' src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1602251573001-a27aafb64d64?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHx0b3BpYy1mZWVkfDE4OXxxUFlzRHp2Sk9ZY3x8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&h=200&q=60" />
```

Comment: Да это то понятно, что проблема получения состояния. Плюс используются не только эти функции трансформации, а те же `scaleX` и `scaleY` отвечают еще и за масштаб. Я потому и использую `getComputedStyle(img).transform`. В любом случае, спасибо за старание, буду разбираться.

Comment: Добавил масштабирование в пример. В принципе можно расширять стейт по мере необходимости.

Comment: Теперь у меня возникла другая проблема, перемещение `translate` применяется с учетом `rotate()`. То есть, если повернуть картинку на 90 градусов, то translateX и translateY тоже надо менять местами. `getComputedStyle()` решает эту проблему.

Comment: То есть, если переместить картинку от начального местоположения, и начать вращать её, картинка улетает за пределы экрана. Если накладывать трансформацию на старую матрицу, то вращение происходит на месте. Картинка зумится по колесику с `transform-origin` настроенным на положение курсора на картинке.. Получается эффект масштабирования как в фотошопе: типа во время масштабирования картинка под курсором никуда не уходит - влево-вправо, вверх-вниз (я не знаю как это объяснить), скорее это проще показать на видео))

Comment: Я добавил translate в пример, ничего не "улетает". Думаю, что проблема действительно с transform-origin. Надо что-бы было transform-origin: center;

Comment: Разобрался, проблема была в порядке функций - `translate()` стояла за `rotate()`.

Answer (score 1):

Помоги браузеру явно указав, что и откуда трансформируется:

```js
function disableButtons() {
  document.body.classList.add('disabled');
  setTimeout(() => document.body.classList.remove('disabled'), 1000);
}

function pushTransform(f, neutral, desired) {
  disableButtons();
  let current = getComputedStyle(img).transform;
  if (current === 'none') current = '';
  img.style.transition = "none";
  img.style.transform = `${current} ${f}(${neutral})`;
  getComputedStyle(img).transform;
  img.style.transition = "";
  img.style.transform = `${current} ${f}(${desired})`;
}

rotate90.onclick  = () => { pushTransform('rotate', '0deg', '90deg')  }
rotate270.onclick = () => { pushTransform('rotate', '0deg', '-90deg') }
flipX.onclick     = () => { pushTransform('scaleY', '1',    '-1')     }
flipY.onclick     = () => { pushTransform('scaleX', '1',    '-1')     }
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  float: left;
  clear: right;
  width: max-content;
}

div button {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  user-select: none;
  margin: .3rem;
  border: 2px solid #f0f;
  cursor: pointer;
}

body {
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 2 2" fill="gray" stroke="none"><rect x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1"/><rect x="1" y="1" width="1" height="1"/></svg>') 16px/16px repeat;
  perspective: 100vh;
}

img,
.disabled * {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.disabled button {
  color: #666;
  background: #ddd;
  border: 2px solid #444;
}

.disabled button:hover {
  color: #666;
  background: #ddd;
  border: 2px solid #444;
}

img {
  transition: all 1000ms linear;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
  will-change: transform;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="rotate90">повернуть<br>по часовой</button>
  <button id="rotate270">повернуть<br>против часовой</button>
  <button id="flipX">отразить<br>по вертикали</button>
  <button id="flipY">отразить<br>по горизонтали</button>
</div>
<img id='img' src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1602251573001-a27aafb64d64?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHx0b3BpYy1mZWVkfDE4OXxxUFlzRHp2Sk9ZY3x8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&h=200&q=60" />
```